# How to write data to a file on iOS in the background

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that runs continuously in the background and needs to write data to a file.  Occasionally I am finding a partial record written to the file so I have added some additional code to try and ensure that even if the app is backgrounded it will still have some chance of completing any writes.

Here is the code so far, and it seems to work but I am still not really sure if the APIs that I am using are the best ones for this job.

For example, is there a better way of opening the file and keeping it open so as to not have to seek to the end of the file each time ?

Is the approach for marking the task as a background task correct to ensure that iOS will allow the task to complete - it executes approximately once every second.

```
 /// We wrap this in a background task to ensure that task will complete even if the app is switched to the background
 /// by the OS
 func asyncWriteFullData(dataString: String, completion: (() -> Void)?) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        let taskID = self.beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        self.writeFullData(dataString)

        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)

        if (completion != nil) {
            completion!()
        }

    })
}
func beginBackgroundUpdateTask() -> UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({})
}

func endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(taskID)
}
/// Write the record out to file.  If the file does not exist then
/// create it.
private func writeFullData(dataString: String) {


    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if let filePath = self.fullDataFilePath {

    if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(filePath) {

        if filemgr.isWritableFileAtPath(filePath) {

            let file: NSFileHandle? = NSFileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: filePath)

            if file == nil {
                // This is a major problem so best notify the User 
                // How are we going to handle this type of error ?
                DebugLog("File open failed for \(self.fullDataFilename)")
                AlertManager.sendActionNotification("We have a problem scanning data, please contact support.");

            } else {
                let data = (dataString as
                    NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                file?.seekToEndOfFile()
                file?.writeData(data!)
                file?.closeFile()
            }

        } else {
            //print("File is read-only")
        }

    } else {
        //print("File not found")

        if createFullDataFile() {
            // Now write the data we were asked to write
            writeFullData(dataString)
        } else {
            DebugLog("Error unable to write Full Data record")
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: there's an atomic version of writeDataToFile

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `NSOutputStream`. In addition, GCD IO can also deal your work.

[Techniques for Reading and Writing Files Without File Coordinators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html)

Comment: How will things work if iOS or the user kills the app while the NSOutputStream is open ?  Will iOS cleanly close any open files or are there steps I will need to take to ensure there are not problems?